# How to separate Model from Provider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-change-notifier

Assume we have a model in our models/ folder:

```dart
class ProductModel {
  final String id;
  ProductModel(this.id);
}
```

and then we create a provider for this model in providers/ folder accordingly:

```dart
class ProductProvider with ChangeNotifier {...}
```

The question is how to make the model being extended in this provider so that we avoid duplication? The solution:

```dart
class ProductProvider extends ProductModel with ChangeNotifier {...}
```

does not work in case if we later create another provider `ProductsProvider` (plural) for lists.

Comment: What is the purpose of `ProductProvider`?

Comment: Why are you providing a model?  You should be providing a business logic class.  Models should be independent of the UI.

Comment: https://github.com/FilledStacks/flutter-tutorials/tree/master/010-provider-architecture/002-final/lib you can follow this architecture.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Provider-ChangeNotifier Architecture is a bit different than what you show, but you are mostly there.

You should have:

```dart
class ProductViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  ProductModel(this.id);
}
```

And that's it, now you can pass this `ProductViewModel` using a `ChangeNotifierProvider`, as you can see [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).